# Polite way of speaking

Tags: sentence-construction

Professor: who are you? What's your name?
Student : May I know who is asking?

Is the student part i.e., "May I know who is asking?" polite enough? or if there is some other better way of putting it, please suggest.

Sorry for providing incomplete details

This conversation is happening inside a college. The student knows that the person is a professor but from an entirely different department i.e., professor knows that the person is a student and vice versa but nothing more. For some reason (unknown to the student), the professor is trying to know the student's name.

Comment: Does the student already know who the professor is? Are they in the professor's class? What are the circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Professor:** Who are you? What's your name?
>
> **Student:** May I know who is asking?

First, when asked your name, it is polite to *answer the question* before asking for the other person's name in return. So this would be more polite:

> **Professor:** Who are you? What's your name?
>
> **Student:** My name is Mohan. May I know who is asking?

Second, the student's question is not very idiomatic. It *almost* sounds like something you would say on the phone if you didn't recognize the other person's voice. ("May I ask who is calling?") In a face-to-face meeting, it just sounds odd and too formal.

It would sound more natural to simply return the question. This is less *formal*, but not less *polite*.

> **Professor:** Who are you? What's your name?
>
> **Student:** My name is Mohan. What's your name?

Comment: I think your answer would be better as a comment as it barely answers the question (by saying it's probably rude, which I don't believe is correct) and then creates an imaginary story where the student already knows the professor, which isn't part of the question. It goes off topic into a discussion on ettiquette and interpersonal skills. There is another stack exchange site for questions about personal skills where this answer would work, had this question been asked there.

Comment: @Smartybartfast Since the OP didn't give any context for the conversation, I had to try and guess what the context would be. But you have a point: I may have guessed incorrectly. I have updated my answer accordingly. I have also removed the most off-topic portion (keeping in mind that the OP is asking for what to say, in English, that would be considered "polite", so I cannot neglect discussion of etiquette entirely).

Comment: Since the OP has added context, I have edited the question further.

Answer (score 1):

That is polite. About the only way to make it more polite would be to add a "please" somewhere, perhaps at the end,

> "May I know who is asking, please?"

Comment: Going off topic into interpersonal skills and etiquette, I don't know context but that the student is asking the question indicates they don't know who the identity of the professor so asking is a perfectly valid thing to do. While people in positions of authority sometimes forget these two things it would be good for them to remember that:

 1. they're not so important that everyone knows who they are
 2. it is polite to introduce oneself before demanding the identity of another